# Detect which element is in the viewport and apply class

Tags: javascript

What I'm trying to do is find all 'section' elements, detect which one is in the viewport and apply a className to the current section. The className should be removed again when scrolling out of the viewport.

Here are the basics. I haven't included all methods and functions of the plugin, just what's needed to help answer the question:

```
// A simple forEach() implementation for Arrays, Objects and NodeLists.
// By Todd Motto
var forEach = function (collection, callback, scope) {
    if (Object.prototype.toString.call(collection) === '[object Object]') {
        for (var prop in collection) {
            if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(collection, prop)) {
                callback.call(scope, collection[prop], prop, collection);
            }
        }
    } else {
        for (var i = 0, len = collection.length; i < len; i++) {
            callback.call(scope, collection[i], i, collection);
        }
    }
};

// Determine if an element is the viewport or not
var _isInViewport = function (elem) {
    var rect = elem.getBoundingClientRect();
    return (
        rect.top >= 0 &&
        rect.left >= 0 &&
        rect.bottom <= (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight) &&
        rect.right <= (window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth)
    );
};

// Get all sections and 
var _getSections = function () {

    var sections = document.querySelectorAll('section');

    forEach(sections, function (section) {

        if (section._isInViewport) {
            section(_isInViewport).classList.add('section-is-in-view');
            alert('yest');
        } else {
            section(_isInViewport).classList.remove('not-in-view');
        }

    });

};


// The event handler
var _eventHandler = function (event) {

    if (event.type === 'scroll') {
        _getSections();
    }

};


// Initialise the plugin
plugin.init = function (options) {

    // Listen for scroll events and run event handler
    document.addEventListener('scroll', _eventHandler, false);

}
```

Note: once it's working correctly, I plan to add some sort of debounce and throttler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This immmediate thing that jumps out at me: this is wrong:

```
if (section._isInViewport) {
```

`_isInViewport` requires you to pass the element in as an argument, like so:

```
if (_isInViewport(section)) {
```

You also don't need to check the event type in the event handler. Since you're only calling that on scroll, you already know the event type is a scroll event. Instead of thing:

```
if (event.type === 'scroll') {
    _getSections();
}
```

You want this:

```
_getSections();
```